# C# forcing static data member in subclass

Tags: c#, oop, opengl, inheritance, static

Is it possible to force a static data member in inherited subclasses?

Here is my problem/thought process:

I want to make a "GameObject' base class that all other objects inherit from to lend to polymorphism.

I want each inherited class to have a static data member list of vertexes to render the polygons.  The exact process would be:

- Create object based on static list of vertexes
- Apply textures
- Rotate object based on instanced object's rotation variables
- Transform object based on instanced object's world coordinates

for all objects that inherit from Game Object, I'd like to guarantee that it has the static vertex list

Should I care if it has the list or not, or should I just care that it has a draw method (guaranteed by an interface iRender)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the GameObject is an interface, then you can enforce the existence of a `static Property`.

```
interface GameObject
{
     static List<vertex> vertices {get; set;}
     //other common code
};
```

Alternatively, you could just have the list of vertices as a protected data member in `GameObject` itself, and have the derived classes access it.

Comment: would i make GameObject an interface or a base class?  does polymorphism work with interfaces?  How would that look?

also, if I put the list in the interface, wouldn't it create a vertex list for every instanced object?  I'm trying to just use 1 poly list for all similar object instances, and then just have individual transformation information for specific instances

Comment: GameObject would be an interface. Polymorphism works *only* with interfaces (and at most one class) in C#.

Comment: I get "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item'. Doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

By virtue of inheritance, a `protected static List<Vertex>` in the base class is automatically part of any derived classes. This should work as long as you don't need each derived class to have its own list separate from the list in any parent class.

Comment: it would need to be separate since they are different game object types (for instance imagine I had a house game object, and then i had a tree game object.  they would have different lists of verticies since they are different objects).  I was going to have a base class game object so i can put all game objects into a loop and say GameObject.Draw(), or something like that.

Comment: That's the point of inheritance - if the base class defines the list, any derived class has the list as part of its definition. The list isn't a `house` list or a `tree` list; it's an `object` list. Two classes that derive from the same base class are still separate classes; even if they share parts of their definitions, they don't have any data in common. The list in a `tree` class wouldn't be the same list as a list in a `house` class.

Comment: right, but what i'm saying is that i dont want a list for every instanced object.  It should be one list of the verticies shared by all instances of that particular inherited object.  Would having protected static List<vertex> let me have a different static list for every sub-object?

Answer (score 1):

There is a single instance of a static class member declared in a base class for all descendants and the base class itself. Therefore a single list of vertices in a base class will not do. What can be done:
- in the base class declare

```
private static Dictionary<string, List<vertex>> PointsPerClass = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<vertex>>();
```

You did not say how descendants specify their vertices, but let's say there a virtual base class method overwritten by all descendants:

```
protected virtual FillStaticVertices(List<vertex> aVertices)
{
}
```

Then the base class has public method:

```
public GameObject CreateObject()
{
    string key = GetType().FullName;
    List<vertex> points = null;
    if (PointsPerClass.ContainsKey(key))
      points = PointsPerClass[key];
    else {
      points = new List<vertex>();
      PointsPerClass.Add(key, points);
      FillStaticVertices(points);
    }

    // CreateObjectFromPoints is an abstract method implemented by descendants
    GameObject gameObj = CreateObjectFromPoints(points);
    // apply textures, rotations, etc

    return gameObj;
}
```